# What is the difference between two URL input boxes in Facebook Ad Manager?

Tags: advertising, facebook, tracking, url-parameters, facebook-ads-manager

I'm unable to understand these two boxes for tracking links:
[image: firefox_2019-10-04_14-38-29.png]
[image]

I understand that the first one is the link used in the ad. If so, then what is the second one is for?

Comment: Did you click the little (i) icon to the right of "URL Prarameters (optional) to read the official explanation?

Comment: Yes. They don't explain much. They only helpful for those who don't know about url parameters, and not explain the difference between the two boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first box is for setting up the landing URL on your site.  The URL that is specified (along with all its tracking information) is sent to your site when the user clicks on the ad.

The second box is for setting up conversion tracking using the Facebook pixel.   It gives you code to put on your "thank you for your purchase" page that sends data back to Facebook letting FB know that the user performed your desired action on your site.

Comment: So I get that the first box is for Google Analytics, and the second box is for Facebook Pixel. Is that correct? I see that both use the same parameters (`utm_source`, `utm_medium`, `utm_campaign`). If I use both boxes, isn't the data will be screwed up in both Google Analytics and Facebook Pixel?

Comment: The first is for clicks to your site.   The `utm` parameters are so that the clicks will get registered in Google Analytics.   I'm not sure exctly why `utm` parameters would be on the conversion tracking.  It is possible that it helps it end up in the GA conversion reports.